# Ios nsarray sorting when in index one more array value

Tags: ios, sorting

I know sorting simple array but this is difficult. I have sort in array index value one more array parameter i have to sort , in simple way i have facing one more array value so i confuse how to sort this type of area Here is my array **this is index no 0 value , in this array name is TODAY array value check_in parameter i have to Sort**

```
{

        address = dsfsd;
        allergies = Dsf;
        annotation = Sdf;
        "birth_date" = "0000-00-00";
        "category_id" = 2;
        "child_id" = 3;
        today =         {
            "check_in" = "7:30 AM";
            "check_out" = "7:30 AM";
            "child_id" = 3;
            "children_schedule_id" = 6;
            day = Wednesday;
            "on_off" = 1;
        };
        weight = sdfsd;
        "work_hours" = dsfds;
    },
```

here is my code

```
 NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"today.check_in" ascending:YES];
                  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstDescriptor, nil];
                  aryOne = [getData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator` for complex sorts.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
  NSString *checkIn1 = obj1[@"today"][@"check_in"];
  NSString *checkIn2 = obj2[@"today"][@"check_in"];
  // You could convert them to dates or times here if you want. Or just compare the strings.
  return [checkIn1 compare:checkIn2];
}];
```

Comment: Hello sir , i don't understand why we use checkIn2 parameter AND what should i convert checkin1 or check 2

Comment: Your comparator is going to compare two objects: `obj1` and `obj2`. Here, we have assigned `checkIn1` the `@"check_in"` value of `obj1`.  Similarly, `checkIn2` has been assigned the value of `@"check_in"` from `obj2`. These values are compared and the result is returned from the block to the sort process.

Comment: Its Working Thankyou , just one Question this code return a descending order but i want ascending order .... please Help me

Comment: Reverse the compare: `[checkIn2 compare:checkIn1]`.